# How to inspect anonymous inner classes within GWT generators?

Tags: gwt

The [TypeOracle](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/TypeOracle.html) in GWT 2.4 doesn't appear to include [metadata](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/JClassType.html) for anonymous inner classes:  do we have other options for inspecting such classes at compile time? I'd specifically like to be able to inspect all (possibly anonymous) implementations of a marker interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get this kind of info from `TypeOracle` (anonymous classes are even absent from Compile Metrics). You can try to get it from AST tree by specifying parameter `-Dgwt.jjs.dumpAst=<path_to_file_for_dumping_tree>`, but this not going to be so useful since this file will be created at the end of Precompile stage, when all the generators have been already invoked.

Comment: I suspected this would be the case. Metadata were indeed required inside a generator. Back to the drawing board…